# How do i make my combo box fill remaining cells with data of one cell

Tags: excel, combobox

am trying to make my combo box fill data in one column basing on the selected value in the list, have tried but all in vein.
I want such that if i select a company in the combo box , it is fill in all cells of column D[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6cWl.png)

Comment: What do you want to fill column D _with_?

Comment: i want such that when i select X-oil, it goes in all cells of column D such that from D1 to D20, there is X-oil as the value

Comment: Fill the column with the following formula `=D$2`

Comment: but i want such that what ever i select in the combo box, it goes into the column

Comment: thanx cyber it has worked